# Java 1.6 and DB2

Tags: java, db2, websphere

Our enterprise code only compiles on Java 1.6, I tried 1.7, but it lead to horrible compilation problems that we can't resolve at this time. We use IBM RAD for our IDE and Websphere 8.5 server to deploy the EAR on our local machines.  Would there be an issue to keep compiling with 1.6, while JAVA sends out new updates in the future?

We use DB2 with JCC4 for DB.

Comment: You can keep compiling with 1.6 for as long as you like. Oracle is only currently providing updates for JDK 11 and 12. All previous versions have reached their end of life. Note: "Java" isn't spelled with ALL CAPS (it's not an acronym).

Comment: Do you have any Java stored-procedures in Db2, or Java User-Defined-Functions in Db2?

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  I really don't know if we do or not.  Could that be an issue that I should keep in my mind?

Comment: Depends on  how far ahead you are planning... while currently shipping Db2-server versions that run on Linux/Unix/Windows continue to support  SDK 6 and 7, that won't remain the case...    If you are asking about Db2 you should find out whether you have any java code running inside Db2-server, and how that code gets built (some companies use the IBM SDK as supplied by the Db2-server to build java routines , separately from client-side code which may be built with different SDK.

Comment: You are unsecure if you can't keep up with updates.

Comment: Yeah, I try to tell them that...we run servlets as well and I know those aren't good neither.  So one guy thought he was good and mixed (with nesting) HTML, JavaScript, and Servlets and shadowed variable names throughout..I'm trying to refactor it, but it's hard to follow what's going on where. And I can't ask my boss anything because he doesn't know how to code or is too scared to promote....so I'm on an island by myself, because the team is just him and I.  He just works on templated SQL help desk tickets that he fills in :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no more updates to Java 6. As per [official page](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_6.xml) you would have to pay Oracle to send you updates to Java 6 (and I'm not sure if this is even possible any more):

> Oracle offers updates to Java 6 only for customers who have purchased Java support or have Oracle products that require Java 6.

Since Java 12 you can't even compile down to Java 6 (see [JDK-8028563 : Remove javac support for 6/1.6 source and target values](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8028563).

On the other hand Java 6 is very stable. There is certain stability in death...

Comment: Thanks, so in RAD, if I go to Pref's => JAVA => Compiler... there's a drop-down that reaches all the way back to JAVA 1.3 (1.3-1.7 range), so I guess I can still compile down to 1.3.  Hopefully 1.6 stays on that list....